# How to create a function for adding an object created by the same function into array?

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I am creating html game where i generate platforms by manually adding them into the array
platforms, therefore I created a function that will adding objects into that array. But it throws an error:

**canvas.bundle.js:230 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))**

```
let generation = ( object, array, image, y ) => {
  array = [... array, new object({
    x: LastPos, y, image
  })]
  LastPos = image.width + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
}

generation(Platform,platforms,platformImage,470)
```

- The reason to create that function is the attempt to make infinity game (runner)

*the function execution will be in the loop*

**P.S** object to be generating is the class:

```
class Platform {  
  constructor({x, y, image}) {
    this.position = {
      x, y
    }
    this.image = image
    this.width = image.width
    this.heigth = image.height

  }
  draw() {
    c.drawImage(this.image, this.position.x, this.position.y)
  }
}
```

Comment: Trying to spread an object into an array as `[ ...obj ]` makes no sense here. The correct syntax would be `[ obj ]` but that creates an array with one element. Are you trying to add to *existing* array called `array`? Then it's just `array.push(obj)`. Or `array = array.concat(obj)` / `array = [ ...array, obj ]` but both of these might come with a performance hit. Yet there is also any `arrayS` that you accept but don't use. So, it's unclear what should actually be happening.

Comment: "arrayS" was an mistake

Comment: array = [array, new object (...)] throws an object is not a constructor

Comment: So, you're accepting an array and want to add to it. Do you expect that to be treated as immutable? If so you cannot just do `array = newThing` as it won't change the passed in argument. You can only mutate the array.

Comment: "*array = [array, new object (...)] throws an object is not a constructor*" then you're also not passing a constructor? I don't know *what* you're passing nor why you want to treat it as a constructor.